# fortune: recreate .dat file

Tags: bash, fortune

`man fortune` states

```
If  a  particular set of fortunes is particularly unwanted, there is an
   easy solution: delete the associated .dat file.  This leaves  the  data
   intact,  should  the  file later be wanted, but since fortune no longer
   finds the pointers file, it ignores the text file.
```

Should the file later be wanted how is the .dat file created ?

Comment: Using the `strfile` utility I believe - see [Creating a Fortunes file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36523/creating-a-fortunes-file)